# Optional navigation property is not being loaded

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-4.1, lazy-loading

I can't for the life of me figure out why Entity Framework (4.1, Code First) is not materializing an optional navigation property.

**POCOs:**

```
public class PlanMember {
    public Int64 Id { get; set; }

    public String FirstName { get; set; }

    public virtual SystemUser CaseManager { get; set; }

    public String LastName { get; set; }

    public virtual PlanMemberStatus Status { get; set; }
}

public class SystemUser {
    public String EMail { get; set; }

    public String FirstName { get; set; }

    public String Id { get; set; }

    public String LastName { get; set; }
}

public class PlanMemberStatus {
    public Int32 Id { get; set; }

    public String Code { get; set; }
}
```

**Configuration Classes:**

```
public class ForPlanMemberEntities:EntityTypeConfiguration<PlanMember> {
    public ForPlanMemberEntities(String schemaName) {
        this.HasOptional(e => e.CaseManager)
            .WithMany()
            .Map(m => m.MapKey("CaseManagerID"));
        this.HasRequired(e => e.Status)
            .WithMany()
            .Map(m => m.MapKey("StatusID"));
        this.ToTable("PlanMember", schemaName);
    }
}

public class ForSystemUserEntities:EntityTypeConfiguration<SystemUser> {
    public ForSystemUserEntities(String schemaName) {
        this.ToTable("SystemUser", schemaName);
    }
}

public class ForPlanMemberStatusEntities:EntityTypeConfiguration<PlanMemberStatus> {
    public ForPlanMemberStatusEntities(String schemaName) {
        this.ToTable("PlanMemberStatus", schemaName);
    }
}
```

**Context:**

```
public class Context:DbContext {
    public DbSet<PlanMember> PlanMemberDbSet { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        var schemaName = Properties.Settings.Default.SchemaName;
        modelBuilder.Configurations
            .Add(new Configuration.ForPlanMemberEntities(schemaName))
            .Add(new Configuration.ForPlanMemberStatusEntities(schemaName))
            .Add(new Configuration.ForSystemUserEntities(schemaName))
            ;
    }
}
```

Based on that configuration, if I run a query like the following it will not populate the `CaseManager` property. The `PlanMemberStatus` property loads just fine.

```
var test = (from member in PlanMemberDbSet
            where member.CaseManager != null
            select member).First();
var cm = test.CaseManager;
```

In my example `cm` is always `null`, despite the fact that - logically speaking - it should be impossible. Any thoughts?

**EDIT** - If I do `PlanMemberDbSet.Include("CaseManager")` then it works as expected. Why is this necessary? In other scenarios I haven't had to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that the `CaseManagerID` foreign key column value in the `PlanMember` table is different to the `Id` primary key column value in table `SystemUser` - different for .NET but not for SQL Server (with standard sorting system), for example different in casing: "**a**" in `CaseManagerID` but "**A**" in `Id`.

Querying for `!= null` (translates into `IS NOT NULL` in SQL) works, so you get indeed only the `PlanMember` entities which have a `SystemUser` assigned in the database. Also the query by the `CaseManager` (triggered by lazy loading) is correctly executed in the database (INNER JOIN) and transmitted to the client. Even the object materialization works (there are 2 objects in the context). But EF fails to relate the loaded `PlanMember` with the loaded `CaseManager` because the keys are not identical (for example with respect to capital/small letters). As a result your navigation property is `null`.

This doesn't occur with the `Status` navigation property because the key is an `Int32`.

The problem looks closely related to this one: [EF 4.1 Code First bug in Find/Update. Any workaround? Should it be reported?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7848644/ef-4-1-code-first-bug-in-find-update-any-workaround-should-it-be-reported/7851831#7851831)

Comment: Your first paragraph is 100% correct. The `PlanMember` table had values all in upper-case, where the `SystemUser` table had values all in lower-case. Once I made them both the same case it magically works. Absolutely a bug, IMO.